# Chessboard calibration at 45 degrees

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am trying to get the corner points of a chessboard using findChessboardCorners function of opencv but it is not working for chessboard when it is slanted at 45 degrees. I specifically need for a slanted chessboard as I need these corner points for transforming the image to birds eye view.

As I said , I have used findChessboardcorners on a chessboard image at 45 degrees to the camera. My code works for normally inclinated image but I specifically want for the one below. would be of great help , thanks.

[image: the chessboard at 45 degree angle]

```
img = cv2.imread('final0-3_painted.png')

# Define the number of corners in the chessboard
num_rows = 12
num_cols = 7

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# Find the chessboard corners in the image
chessboard_flags = cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, (num_rows,num_cols), chessboard_flags)
print(corners)
```

Comment: the chessboard is not fully visible on the left side. Can you provide an image where detection fails but the whole chessboard is visible?

Comment: Hello Micka , I currently do not have a fully visible chessboard for this angle. would it work if I recreate the missing the parts using GIMP?

Comment: then at least you would have a chance... You could also try to reduce the num_rows  and num_cols  in your code. It is important to mention that opencv tries to find the INNER corners of a chessboard, so if you have a chessboard with 8x6 squares you would have to parametrize a 7x5 size in findChessboardCorners.

Comment: 7x11 might work in your image.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I am mainly interested in finding the rotation matrix of this image so I manually entered the corner points for now. Because I have tried with 7*11 and even lesser , still no detection. but anyway I will try retaking the picture where I can get full chessboard.

Comment: you could try to photoshop-away bigger parts of your chessboard, so that the algorithm has a much smaller and complete chessboard fully visible.

Comment: iI can detect a 9x3 pattern in an image with smaller board and increased contrast: https://ibb.co/0qNQ3L7 the blue parts and drawn with GIMP, to remove black/white parts of the image. Maybe using an imag with better lighting (more white/black than red/brown in the chessboard) could help.